# Difference b/w intrinsic locking, client side locking & extrinsic locking?

Tags: java, multithreading

what is the difference b/w intrinsic locking, client side locking & extrinsic locking ?

What is the best way to  create a thread safe class ?

which kind of locking is prefered & why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of "private final Object" locking in java multithreading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419702/what-is-the-use-of-private-final-object-locking-in-java-multithreading)

Comment: Hi dirk, Please don't mark it as duplicate. This is a different question than other one. These are not related. I have posted this separately from the other one. By the way i have n't got any appropriate & satisfactory answer on the other posted question

Answer (score 11):

I would highly recommend you to read "[Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)" by Brian Goetz. It is an excellent book that will help you to understand all the concepts about concurrency!

About your questions, I am not sure if I can answer them all, but I can give it a try. Most of the times, if the question is "what is the best way to lock" etc, the answer is always it depends on what problem you try to solve.

**Question 1:**

What you try to compare here are not exactly comparable;

Java provides a built in mechanism for locking, the `synchronized` block. Every object can implicitly act as a lock for purposes of synchronization; these built-in locks are called *intrinsic locks*.

What is interesting with the term `intrinsic` is that the ownership of a lock is per thread and not per method invocation. That means that only one thread can hold the lock at a given time. What you might also find interesting is the term `reentrancy`, which allows the same thread to acquire the same lock again. Intrinsic locks **are** reentrant.

*Client side locking*, if I understand what you mean, is something different. When you don't have a thread safe class, your clients need to take care about this. They need to hold locks so they can make sure that there are not any race conditions.

*Extrinsic locking* is, instead of using the built in mechanism of synchronized block which gives you implicit locks to specifically use **explicit** locks. It is kind of more sophisticate way of locking. There are many advantages (for example you can set priorities). A good starting point is the [java documentation about locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

**Question 2:**
It depends :) The easiest for me is to try to keep everything immutable. When something is immutable, I don't need to care about thread safety anymore

**Question 3:**
I kind of answered it on your first question

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that discuss the different locking schemes:

[Explicit versus Intrinsic](http://mishrabagish.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/explicit-vs-intrinsic-locks-in-java-ensuring-thread-scheduling-fairness)

[Client side locking and when to avoid it](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK11-J.+Avoid+client-side+locking+when+using+classes+that+do+not+commit+to+their+locking+strategy)

I don't know that there is a "best" way to create a thread safe class, it depends on what you are trying to achieve exactly. Usually you don't have to make the whole class thread safe, only guard the resources that different threads all have access to, such as common lists etc.

Answer (score 2):

Explicit  - locking using concurrent lock utilities like Lock interface. eg - `ConcurrentHashMap`

Intrinsic - locking using `synchronized`.

Client side locking  - Classes like `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't support Client side locking because get method is not using any kind of lock. so although you put a lock over its object like synchronized (object of `ConcurrentHashMap`) still some other thread can access object of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Classes having all set get methods Explicit or Intrinsic locks are supporting client side locking. As some client code come and lock over that object. below is example of Vector

```
public static Object getLast(Vector list) {
    synchronized (list) {
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
        return list.get(lastIndex);
    }
}

public static void deleteLast(Vector list) {
    synchronized (list) {
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
        list.remove(lastIndex);
    }
}
```