# Synchronize on Integer does not lock correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, synchronized

I have some code using `synchronized` to protect a counter that I increment `count++`.

I would expect that I protected the code section correctly and hence get `2_0000_0000` as result, since that would be the correct value for `count` after executing it that many times, multithreaded.

However, when running the code, I get a value below the expected `2_0000_0000`, as if my `synchronized` did not protect the code section correctly.

Why is that the case, what did I do wrong?

```java
public class Test {
    private static Integer count = 0;

    private static void add10K() {
        long idx = 0;
        while (idx++ < 1_0000_0000) {
            synchronized (count){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static long calc() {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(Test::add10K);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(Test::add10K);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        try {
            th1.join();
            th2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're synchronizing on `count`. And since `Integer` is immutable, that's a new object for every new value.

Comment: You are locking on a non `final` variable, that is just asking for a catastrophe. Only ever lock on `final` variables. Create a dedicated `private static final Object lock = new Object();` and synchronize on that instead.

Comment: @Turing85: AtomicInteger would be better, but synchronized would be sufficient if used correctly.

Comment: @JoachimSauer true that. Did not realize that the object changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem description

Javas `synchronized` stores the lock in the actual object behind the variable, not in the variable itself.

So when you assign a different object to the variable, you have a new fresh lock.

Now, when you do `count++`, this actually does not modify the `Integer` but give back a new `Integer` object (the class is **immutable**). So the `count` variable is re-assigned.

---

To help explaining my point, consider the following situation:

```
Person person = new Person("John");
...
synchronized (person) {
    ...
}
```

The lock is stored in *John*, not in the variable `person` itself. So when someone now does:

```
person = new Person("Jane");
```

The `synchronized` block is **not protected anymore** and can be entered again, since there is no lock in *Jane* yet.

---

### Object Lock Idiom

This is why locks should only ever be put on `final` variables, to avoid exactly this issue. Furthermore, you should dedicate a specific object just for this purpose. The idiomatic fix for your situation is:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and then synchronize on that instead:

```
synchronized (lock) { ... }
```

The other very common choices are to lock on the class or `this` (for non-static situations). So for example `synchronized (Test.class)`. Having a dedicated object for it has some advantages though.

---

### Resources

If you like books, refer to [**Effective Java**](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java/9780134686097/), **Item 82** explaining the **private object lock idiom**:

> Note  that  the  lock field is declared final. This prevents you from inadvertently changing its contents, which could result in catastrophic unsynchronized access (Item 78). We are applying the advice of Item 17, by minimizing the mutability of the lock field. **Lock  fields  should  always  be  declared  final.**

Also see the SO thread about [What is the use of “private final Object” locking in java multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419835/2411243)

And finally the [Oracle Secure Coding Standard§Rule 09. Locking (LCK)#LCK00-J.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK00-J.+Use+private+final+lock+objects+to+synchronize+classes+that+may+interact+with+untrusted+code) itself:

> One technique for preventing this vulnerability is the private lock object idiom [Bloch 2001]. This idiom uses the intrinsic lock associated with the instance of a private final java.lang.Object declared within the class instead of the intrinsic lock of the object itself. This idiom requires the use of synchronized blocks within the class's methods rather than the use of synchronized methods. Lock contention between the class's methods and those of a hostile class becomes impossible because the hostile class cannot access the private final lock object.

Answer (score 2):

Make the following change and it should work.

```
static final private Object lock = new Object(); 
private static void add10K() {
       long idx = 0;
       while (idx++ < 100_000_000) {
                synchronized (lock){
                    count += 1;
                }
       }
}
```

Also, if your methods were not static, you could just synchronize on the instance like so.

```
synchronized (this) {
        count += 1;
}
```

But your thread invocations would need to change as well as your call to `calc()` to refer to instance methods.

Comment: Downvoted: It is peddling an anti-pattern. Remove the comment about locking on a public value without extensively documenting it (`this`, which tends to be a ref that loads of other code can also access) and this is a nice answer. (in fact, that lock object should probably be `private`, and definitely `final`).

Comment: *it is peddling an anti-pattern*.  It's right out of Effective Java 3rd Ed so I'm in good company.

Comment: @rzwitserloot *Downvoted: It is peddling an anti-pattern.* Can I downvote a comment? The posted code does what the posted code does.  Patterns are worse than training wheels - they force-fit code into predefined algorithms that don't fit the job that actually needs to be done.  Phrases such as "peddling an anti-pattern" are bandied about by those that don't understand that and would force square pegs into round holes because someone else said it's a good idea.  "I need to make a triangle."  "No, that's an anti-pattern!  You must make a square!"

Comment: Some nice Appeal to Authority fallacies flying about here. I'll make an actual reasoned argument: Just like a public field is a bad idea (and if you must, best _extensively_ documented, and with an awareness that any change to it or how the class interacts with it has impact on the code that uses the class) a public lock is no different: If a lock is accessible, then other code might lock on it (just like: If a field is accessible, other code might read/write it), and you should document what this means. Or, just like with fields: Usually you just make em private.

Comment: I changed the access restrictions to private and final. But it was not my attempt to provide an in depth tutorial on thread programming.  I was simply providing a solution to address the OP's immediate problem.  It is not necessary to write a tome on every answer to every question or cover all possible cases.

Comment: @rzwitserloot *I'll make an actual reasoned argument: Just like a public field is a bad idea*  They why did you use a meaningless buzzword like "anti-pattern" in the first place?  And FWIW, calling something an "anti-pattern" is the "appeal to authority" - "Someone else called your code an anti-pattern!  You are a heretic bacause THEY said so!"